# Test if a website is alive from a C# application

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am looking for the best way to test if a website is alive from a C# application.

#### Background

My application consists of a *Winforms UI*, a backend *WCF service* and a *website* to publish content to the UI and other consumers. To prevent the situation where the UI starts up and fails to work properly because of a missing WCF service or website being down I have added an app startup check to ensure that all everything is alive.

The application is being written in C#, .NET 3.5, Visual Studio 2008

#### Current Solution

Currently I am making a web request to a test page on the website that will inturn test the web site and then display a result.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/myContentSite/test.aspx");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

I am assuming that if there are no exceptions thown during this call then all is well and the UI can start.

#### Question

Is this the simplest, right way or is there some other sneaky call that I don't know about in C# or a better way to do it.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

As @Yanga mentioned, HttpClient is probably the more common way to do this now.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var checkingResponse = await client.GetAsync(url);
if (!checkingResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Will this work for any site ? Like i am making something similar where it give error on some site but when i put the url in browser it opens fine.

Comment: @confusedMind It could be that the server is returning a code other than a 200 OK status code.  If you look at the list of [HTTP Status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) you'll notice that all 200,300 http codes aren't error codes so in a browser might still load the page as if its fine.

Comment: HTTP 500s will throw exceptions, so the existing check isn't enough. Have a look at the following for catching the exception, and checking the HTTP status code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692342/net-httpwebrequest-getresponse-raises-exception-when-http-status-code-400-ba for

Comment: I think this solution returns requested URL body! How can we only check a URL is alive or not?

Comment: @MohammadAfrashteh You need to get the response to be sure, something simpler like a ping could lead to a false positive as the server could be online but not serving pages.

Comment: OK. But if the requested page body is large (e.g: 100MB <) it is an unreasonable way to be sure! Getting head of the requested resource will be enough to be sure.

Comment: @MohammadAfrashteh I can't say that I've ever encountered a 100MB page or anything even close to that but if it is that important to you, I think if you set request.Method = "HEAD" before calling GetResponse it will not return the content.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 21):

While using WebResponse please make sure that you close the response stream ie (.close) else it would hang the machine after certain repeated execution.
Eg

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
// your code here
response.Close();
```

Comment: Maxymus is right I had a problem with the server not responding to me after a while, but adding the response.Close(); fixed it.

Comment: +1. Closing the response can be easily overlooked (just happened to me).

Comment: I agree but should be: response.Close(); note the case.

Answer (score 10):

from the [NDiagnostics](http://www.codeplex.com/NDiagnostics) project on CodePlex...

```
public override bool WebSiteIsAvailable(string Url)
{
  string Message = string.Empty;
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);

  // Set the credentials to the current user account
  request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
  request.Method = "GET";

  try
  {
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
      // Do nothing; we're only testing to see if we can get the response
    }
  }
  catch (WebException ex)
  {
    Message += ((Message.Length > 0) ? "\n" : "") + ex.Message;
  }

  return (Message.Length == 0);
}
```

Comment: Using HEAD verb can be faster.

Comment: Request for diagnostics utility in All-In-One Code http://1code.codeplex.com/workitem/10118

Answer (score 8):

We can today update the answers using [HttpClient()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
var result = await Client.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com");
int StatusCode = (int)result.StatusCode;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the WCF service and the website live in the same web app, you can use a "Status" WebService that returns the application status. You probably want to do some of the following:

- Test that the database is up and running (good connection string, service is up, etc...)
- Test that the website is working (how exactly depends on the website)
- Test that WCF is working (how exactly depends on your implementation)
- Added bonus: you can return some versioning info on the service if you need to support different releases in the future.

Then, you create a client on the Win.Forms app for the WebService. If the WS is not responding (i.e. you get some exception on invoke) then the website is down (like a "general error").
If the WS responds, you can parse the result and make sure that everything works, or if something is broken, return more information.

Comment: They are unfortunately not in the same web app, but this is not too much of a problem.

I have already created all the tests for the DB and the ORM :) (but thanx for the suggestion)

Comment: real world samples about it ? ***test database, website, WCF, versioning***

Answer (score -3):

You'll want to check the status code for OK (status 200).

Answer (score -3):

Solution from: [How do you check if a website is online in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523741/how-do-you-check-if-a-website-is-online-in-c)

```
var ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();

var result = ping.Send("https://www.stackoverflow.com");

if (result.Status != System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success)
    return;
```

Comment: This only pings the server, i.e. checks to see if the machine is up and running.  It doesn't check if the server respond with information on port 80.