# Web service Error on retrieve a word document

Tags: asp.net, httpwebresponse

I get an error when trying to retrieve word document by webservice

```
            HttpWebRequest request;
            Uri uri = new Uri(serverUrl +
                    "/bare.aspx/" + Request.PathInfo);
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(uri);
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = -1;
            request.Timeout = -1;
            request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            // Serialize argument into request stream
            Hashtable arguments = new Hashtable();
            arguments["templateFile"] = templateFile;
            arguments["hSetDataSource"] = hSetDataSource;
            arguments["hSetRepeatBlock"] = hSetRepeatBlock;
            arguments["messageForEmptyWord"] = messageForEmptyWord;
            arguments["hImageBefore"] = hImageBefore;
            arguments["hImageAfter"] = hImageAfter;
            arguments["hImageInsideRepeater"] = hImageInsideRepeater;
            MemoryStream buf = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
            fmt.Serialize(buf, arguments);
            request.ContentLength = buf.Length;
            Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            buf.WriteTo(reqStream);
            reqStream.Close();
            buf.Close();                

            // Retreive word document from response and return it
            // TODO: refactor this to stream directly into the response 
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

When I check the webservice response (HttpWebResponse resp), I get the following error:

***System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.***

I don't understand where is the problem, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you're trying to hit a webservice, should your URL be bare.asmx and not bare.aspx?

Comment: I tried with 'asmx', but I get the same error

Comment: I find this but Idon't if that can help in my case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692342/net-httpwebrequest-getresponse-raises-exception-when-http-status-code-400-ba

Answer (score 0):

You are not hitting the endpoint.  A `404` means the server could not find the `URL` you are requesting.  Verify your `.asmx` URL by putting it in your web browser.  If that works then make sure you code is using that same URL.

Comment: But this script should create a temporary document ? why he doesn't find it?