# Send Parse Push Notifications with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, parse-platform, push-notification

I have developed an android application with the Parse push notification service and I can send notification from the Parse website.
How can I send push notifications through my own website using ASP.net? Is there any way?

I checked the Parse documentation but i get confused, I would really appreciate it if someone would help me.

Thanks

Comment: have a look on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079917/how-do-i-send-api-push-message-with-net-parse-com-c)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar confusion. I wasn't even sure how to properly setup the user so that I could send a push notification directly to them. Then I found the following post:

[Channels and Targeted Push Notifications](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/targeted-push-notifications/)

Note the last item under the **Channels** heading:

> Most apps might find it useful to have a channel for each user so that
>   they can send messages to a user across all their devices and have
>   users follow others in the app.

So, now I know that I should subscribe each user to a channel that uniquely identifies the user (e.g., the 'bobsmith@foo.org' channel).

After I have subscribed the user to their channel, I can call Parse's REST API via my ASP.NET application. See [Sending Pushes](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications-sending-pushes) in the [Parse REST API Developers Guide](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide).

For an ASP.NET/C# example of how to submit a push notification [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17233758/29613).