# C# Rest API Push Notifications (Parse.com)

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

Is it possible to **RECEIVE** push notifications from parse.com on a C#/.NET Application (not Windows 8 app).

If not possible is there a way for me to get notifications from a web server, preferably without having to manually poll every N seconds?

Comment: Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079917/how-do-i-send-api-push-message-with-net-parse-com-c/17233758#17233758

Comment: But that is sending with C#...i need to receive with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. parse.com just a wrapper for GCM, APNS, etc. 
You can use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) for notifications without any polling.

Comment: Does SignalR work on a traditional c# 4.0 desktop application?