# Is "HEAD" as request-method enough to check if site is reachable

Tags: c#, header, http-headers

We want to check if a site exists/is available by using the following piece of code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "HEAD";
```

As we don't want to download the whole site I thought it might be enough to just get the headers and evaluate them.

Am I missing there some thoughts or is it really enough to check if the website is up and reachable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523741/how-do-you-check-if-a-website-is-online-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, HEAD is probably the best option.

As mentioned in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) :

> This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.