# ASP.NET shared hosting ping - server not available

Tags: hosting, ping

I've noticed on my dev env. timeout sql connection errors when i'm using connection string to remote db.
I've developed a small tool to ping domain and db server based on these answers  [test if a website is alive from a C# applicaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186894/best-way-to-test-if-a-website-is-alive-from-a-c-sharp-applicaiton)
and [test SQL Server connection programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440060/whats-the-best-way-to-test-sql-server-connection-programmatically)

When i noticed Failed pings i looked into site management console and caught that Sql Server is unavailable, the site was down for about 5 minutes.
Since i started monitoring the issue repeated 3 times for the last couple of days. It means that my DB server withing a shared hosting plan is not reliable 24/7, i opened a ticket and got a reply from support:
*As this is a shared server, the activities on the server always varies from time to time. We apologize if there is a slight issue earlier*

Is this a common situation for any shared asp.net hosting? or it is a bad luck and i need to search for another hosting?

Comment: That's very normal on shared hosting environment. I also use shared hosting and for 5 minutes that's very acceptable, unless it down for 24 hours, maybe you can find other hosting provider There are no perfect word for shared hosting and the fact there are no shared hosting can give 100% uptime guarantee. Why? For example, they want to install new software, 1 client that utilize high resource, it might impact to your site. If only 5 minutes, truly, that's really ACCEPTABLE!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when the hosting providers update some service or software it could be down for a few minutes, but this should not happen very often. You could continue monitor the services and if the results are not good you could try another hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

You may experience little slowness or lagging in I/O in shared database servers while database backup script is running in background or any other maintenance are carried out by the web host. But in most cases, they don't affect the server availability.

In fact, shared database servers are really high end servers (mostly SSD base) and are meant to host thousands of databases without single hiccup. They must be capable to handle millions of queries at any point of time. If you face this problem more often then it's straight indication that your web host is overly utilizing the database server resources, or server is no longer capable to handle the load in peak hours.