# How to check if website exists

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm trying to check if website exists using:

```
private bool isExist(string url)
{
    WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
    try
    {
        using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works on WPF, but on UWP doesn't have method GetResponse(). How to do it on UWP app?

Comment: `GetResponseAsync`.

Comment: [`HttpWebResponse.StatusCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode(v=vs.110).aspx) tell you the status of the site.

Comment: Have a look at:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient

Comment: This answer on the linked duplicate candidate is what you are looking for I guess : https://stackoverflow.com/a/186951/6560478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the GetResponseAsync()

```
HttpWebResponse response = await webrequest.GetResponseAsync();
```